# A regular expression for matching a simple word in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

i need a regular expression to match only the word's that match the following conditions. I am using it in my C# program

1. Can be any case
2. Should not have any numbers
3. may contain - and ' characters, but are optional
4. Should start with a letter

I have tried using the expression `^([a-zA-Z][\'\-]?)+$` but it doesn't work.

Here are list of few words that are acceptable

1. London (Case insensitive)
2. Jackson's
3. non-profit

Here are a list of few words that are not acceptable

1. 12london (contains a number and is not started by a alphabet)
2. -to (does not start with a alphabet)
3. to: (contains : character, any special character other that - and  ' is not allowed)

Comment: And you don't want to match words like `touché` or `naïve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z][-'a-zA-Z]*$
```

This matches any word that starts with an alphabetical character, followed by any number of alphabetical characters, - or '.

Note that you don't need to escape the - and ' when it's inside the [character [] class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), as long as the dash is either the first or last character in the sequence.

Note also that I've removed the round brackets from your example - if you don't want to [capture the input](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), you'll get better performance by leaving them out.

Comment: Beat you to that edit, @Jim (or at least, I was very close to beating you to it...)

Comment: +1 but I assume OP needs this regex to work on a text, not on individual words. This regex does not find anything in *In London there's a Jackson's working in the non-profit sector.*

Comment: @Lieven - the OP included the ^ and $, so I assumed that the OP was testing a single word statement like a password or similar. Some modifications will be needed it this isn't the case..

Comment: @Lieven I want to match individual words only, not words in a text, i am using this regular expression as sort of word validator @Dexter Yes, i was indeed using this for matching individual words thank you all

Comment: @Vamsi - all the better but now my curiousity about how to extract those words from a text doesn't get satisfied <vbg>

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z'-]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try your regexes against tools such as http://www.regextester.com/

You are testing strings that both start with AND end with your pattern (^ means start of line, $ is the end), thus leaving out all of the words contained between two spaces.
You should use \b or \B.
Instead of looking for [a-zA-Z] you can use character classes such as '\D' (not digit).
Let me know if the above is working in your scenario.

```
\b\D[^\c][a-zA-Z]+[^\c]
```

It says: word boundaries with no digits, no control characters, one or more alphabetical lower or uppercase character, with no following control characters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i was actually using this regular expression for checking whether the words are in a required format or not, i am not using against a text but only on individual words, there are no spaces between the words.